# How to get only Json content from HttpEntity Java

Tags: java, httpclient, httpentity

Using `HttpEntity` I am getting a very long text which has special characters as well along with Json.

I tried regex but it's not working as it is almost 30000 of characters.

Is there a way that i can only get Json data from the HttpEntity. Even string split did not work since it has so many of special characters.

```
public JSONObject sendGet(String URL, String userName, String password) throws Exception {
    getRequest = new HttpGet(URL);
    getRequest.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password);
    provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
    client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();
    response = client.execute(getRequest);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    outputFile = new File(directoryPath + "/target/response.txt");
    fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    headers = response.getAllHeaders();
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    for (Header header: headers) {
        bw.write(header.getName() + ": " + header.getValue() + "\n");
    }
    bw.write(response.getEntity());
    bw.write("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine());
    String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity); //When i print content it has string other than json as well
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(content); //Here i receive A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    JSONArray keys = obj.names();
    Object test = JSON.parse(content);
    jsonFiles = new File(directoryPath + "/JsonFiles/test.json");
    fos = new FileOutputStream(jsonFiles);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    bw.write(content);
    bw.close();
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code which you have written?

Comment: You need to encode (BASE64) data first before sending if possible. It will preserve ASCII.

Comment: *//When i print content it has string other than json as well* paste an example. BTW why are you getting SOMETHING + JSON actually insteed of plain json?

Comment: How to get plain Json, that's what i want.

Comment: How can we answer if we dont know how actual response look like tell me please.

Comment: I am able to resolve it, i just wrote down the content to json file and only Json data is showing there. However i am not sure why its prints other random message with json whenever i tried to parse the content to Json object directly in code.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following `Headers`:

```
getRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
getRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
getRequest.addHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
```